# Get value of an array that starts with a particular string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array classNameList
My HTML :

```
<ul id="servicepricing">
    <li>
        <a href="/service/page/servicepricing?dpt=4&amp;ServiceModelListId27071" class="ServiceModelListId27071 servicepricingicon">FR-S Automatic</a>
        <span style="display: none;">Scion FR-S Automatic Service Pricing</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/service/page/servicepricing?dpt=4&amp;ServiceModelListId27072" class="ServiceModelListId27072 servicepricingicon">FR-S Manual</a>
        <span style="display: none;">Scion FR-S Manual Service Pricing</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/service/page/servicepricing?dpt=4&amp;ServiceModelListId27061" class="ServiceModelListId27061 servicepricingicon">iQ Automatic</a>
        <span style="display: none;">Scion iQ Automatic Service Pricing</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/service/page/servicepricing?dpt=4&amp;ServiceModelListId124" class="ServiceModelListId124 servicepricingicon">tC Automatic</a>
        <span style="display: none;">Scion tC Automatic Service Pricing</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/service/page/servicepricing?dpt=4&amp;ServiceModelListId125" class="ServiceModelListId125 servicepricingicon">tC Manual</a>
        <span style="display: none;">Scion tC Manual Service Pricing</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

initially i am hiding all the tables and when someone clicks on above anchor link i have to show the table that has that same class name

```
<table id="FR-SManual" class="content sortable pureprice-data servicepricing-view ServiceModelListId27071" style="display: none;">
</table>
<table id="FR-SManual" class="content sortable pureprice-data servicepricing-view ServiceModelListId27072" style="display: none;">
</table>
<table id="FR-SManual" class="content sortable pureprice-data servicepricing-view ServiceModelListId27061" style="display: none;">
</table>
<table id="FR-SManual" class="content sortable pureprice-data servicepricing-view ServiceModelListId2124" style="display: none;">
</table>
<table id="FR-SManual" class="content sortable pureprice-data servicepricing-view ServiceModelListId125" style="display: none;">
</table>


var className,
classNameList = ["servicepricingicon", "main","ServiceModelListId27071"];
```

How can I get value/s of an array that starts with "ServiceModelListId". I tried using this:

```
function fxnShowHide() {
var aElem = this,
    classNameList = $(aElem).attr("class").split(' '),
    tblwdhClassName;

if ($(aElem).hasClass('main')) {
    $("#hero").show();
    $("table.servicepricing-view").hide();
}

$.each(classNameList, function (key, value) {
    if (value.indexOf("ServiceModelListId") === 0) {
        tblwdhClassName = "table.servicepricing-view." + value;
    }
});

$(tblwdhClassName).show();

}
$(".servicepricingicon").click(fxnShowHide);
```

Is there any other process with out .each or for ?

Comment: If you want to check that it starts with the value, change `> -1` to `== 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used $.each functionality

```
var classNameList = $(aElem).attr("class").split(' '),
    elemClassName 


    $.each(classNameList, function (key, value) {
        if (value.indexOf("ServiceModelListId") === 0) {
            elemClassName = "." + value;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (value.substring(0, 7) == "Service") {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var className,
classNameList = ["servicepricingicon", "main","ServiceModelListId27071"];

$.each( classNameList , function( key, value ) {
  var anchor = $("." + classNameList[key]),
      anchorText  = anchor.text(),
      anchorClass = anchor.attr("class");
  
  if (anchorClass.indexOf("Service") > -1) {
        className = anchorText;
        alert(className)
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="servicepricing">
    <li>
        <a href="/service/page/servicepricing?dpt=4&amp;ServiceModelListId27071" class="ServiceModelListId27071 servicepricingicon">FR-S Automatic</a>
        <span style="display: none;">Scion FR-S Automatic Service Pricing</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/service/page/servicepricing?dpt=4&amp;ServiceModelListId27072" class="ServiceModelListId27072 servicepricingicon">FR-S Manual</a>
        <span style="display: none;">Scion FR-S Manual Service Pricing</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/service/page/servicepricing?dpt=4&amp;ServiceModelListId27061" class="ServiceModelListId27061 servicepricingicon">iQ Automatic</a>
        <span style="display: none;">Scion iQ Automatic Service Pricing</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/service/page/servicepricing?dpt=4&amp;ServiceModelListId124" class="ServiceModelListId124 servicepricingicon">tC Automatic</a>
        <span style="display: none;">Scion tC Automatic Service Pricing</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/service/page/servicepricing?dpt=4&amp;ServiceModelListId125" class="ServiceModelListId125 servicepricingicon">tC Manual</a>
        <span style="display: none;">Scion tC Manual Service Pricing</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This selector doesn't work reliably for classes. If the class value is `foo bar ServiceFooBar` this would not work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that is correct now it is working with the update.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : Create an array with name `classsName` and use `.push()` to add value to it. You need to compare `indexOf` value with `0` for checking start with value as `Service`

```
var className = new Array();
$.each(classNameList, function( index, value ) {
  if (value.indexOf("Service") == 0) {
        className.push(value);
   }
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/Lxn1g5br/1/)**

**NOTE** - start with selection is case sensitive